# Using rainlab.user.activate event in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I do not really know why this is not working but i created a new plugin and have some code to run in the boot method when a user is activated. One of it is adding users automatically to a group when they sign up using the code below

```
Event::listen('rainlab.user.activate', function ($user) {
  $group = 
    \Rainlab\User\Models\UserGroup::where('code', 'seller')->first();

   $user->groups()->add($group);
    $user->save(); 

});
```

and this works perfectly ok. Now i want to add a new feature that gives users free credit when they are activated using the code below which seems to work when i try it with a regular ajax request which adds the specified credit to a user.

```
Event::listen('rainlab.user.activate', function ($user) {

  $credit = \Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Credit::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => Auth::getUser()->id]);
        $credit->increment('amount', 500);
        $credit->refresh();

  });
```

This does not seem to work here in the boot method when a user is activated probably because it is not getting the authenticated user or something else. Any insight into why this is?

Comment: What if you changed Auth::getUser()->id to $user->id ?? Couldn't you just do \Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Credit::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $user()->id], [amount => 500]);

Comment: Adding event listeners in the boot method is correct. Did you check the event log for any errors?

Comment: @PettisBrandon That did not work.

Comment: @RajaKhoury no errors there about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the instance returned in the event listener

```
 $credit = \Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Credit::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $user->id]);
        $credit->increment('amount', 500);
        $credit->refresh();

  });
```